# Connection between Google Developer project and the Android App

Tags: android

According to this documentation https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started

Although the clientId is generated, it is not used anywhere in the Android code.

What is the connection between Google Developer project and the Android code and how it is working?

Comment: The Client ID for Android application is generated for Package name your application and the same Certificate fingerprint (SHA1) that you use by creating signed app for GooglePlay.

Comment: but I'm getting authentication error, when signin

Comment: I have made only with Google Drive, For Signing in Debug Mode SDK generates a certificate to sign apps in debug mode.